# Check for value in another list using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a array with 112 elements (item numbers). I also have a list containing 47 elements (item numbers)

Now I want to check if the one of the item numbers in the array with 112 elements exists in the list of 47 elements. If it does not exist, I will do a action.

Here is my code:

```
   for(var i = 0; i < value.Count(); i++) //Value contains 112
    {
        //Response contains 47 elements
        if(!response.Any(x => x.Vo.Item_No == Int32.Parse(value[i])))
        {
            modelBank.Add(new ModelBank { Item_No = value[i].ToString(), Item_Type = "ART", SameAs = "", Status = "3D Missing" });
        }
    }
```

This only adds 2 objects I my modelbank list. I want it do add 65 objects, because 65 is missing.

Am I thinking wrong?

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia: example?

Comment: There seems to be a difference between `value` and `response`, did you clip some code?

Comment: Seems like that should do it - are you sure the data you're filtering is what you expect it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is obviously not what you expect since the following code works as expected, i.e. it adds 65 values to `modelBank`:

```
int[] value = Enumerable.Range(1, 112).ToArray();
int[] response = Enumerable.Range(1, 47).ToArray();
List<int> modelBank = new List<int>();
for (var i = 0; i<value.Length; i++)
{
    if (!response.Any(x => x == value[i]))
    {
        modelBank.Add(value[i]);
    }
}
```

In other words, this should work:

```
var modelBank = value.Where(x=> !response.Any(y => y.Vo.Item_No == Int32.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both elements of the array and list are the same type you can use the List.Contains method to check if is exist.

```
foreach(var item in value)
{
    if(!response.Contains(item))
    {
        //Do your action
    }
}
```